# Free software to design a 10-15 page brochure

Tags: print-design, software-recommendation, page-layout

We're looking forward to invite companies for campus placement for which I have to make a 10-15 page prospectus giving major campus details. It has to definitely look good and professional, so if u guys could be kind enough and suggest some free software or online platform that would be great.

For Photoshop I think making 15 different pages would get tricky.. Or is Photoshop the best option?

Comment: Photoshop is not free! If you have photishop odds are you also have InDesign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Photoshop is a raster image editor and is *not* the tool for the job (well, not for the layout anyway. You most certainly can prepare your images in Photoshop). What you need is desktop publishing software. If you have access to Photoshop you may also have access to [**InDesign**](https://www.adobe.com/InDesign%E2%80%8E), which I would suggest using.

The only free alternative I know of is [**Scribus**](https://www.scribus.net/), which is both free and open source.

[image]